# Positioning of \hdots

Tags: positioning, labels

I want the two `\hdots` being centered between the two = and I also want the `\vdots` being centered under the whole last line. Besides I want the mark (the number of the equation) not being under it.

I am not allowed to change the value of `BCOR`.

Have you got some ideas?
Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,parskip=half-,numbers=noenddot,BCOR=8mm,headheight=29pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%MATHEMATIK
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:1}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
&c_{0}&&=P(Q(0))&&=a_{0}\\
&c_{1}&&=P^{\prime}(Q(0))Q^{\prime}(0)&&=a_{1}b_{1}\\
&c_{2}&&=\frac{P^{\prime\prime}(Q(0))Q^{\prime}(0)^{2}+P^{\prime}(Q(0))Q^{\prime\prime}(0)}{2}&&=a_{2}b_{1}^{2}+a_{1}b_{2}\\
&c_{3}&&=\hdots&&=a_{3}b_{1}^{3}+2a_{2}b_{1}b_{2}+a_{1}b_{3}\\
&c_{4}&&=\hdots&&=b_{1}^{2}(a_{4}b_{1}^{2}+3a_{3}b_{2})+a_{2}(b_{2}^{2}+2b_{1}b_{3})+a_{1}b_{4}\\[-1ex]
\multispan{3}\hfill\vdots\hfill
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What would you do in order to change the position of the line number?

Comment: I show two ways in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no hope of getting the display to fit in the given text width, unless you split up one of the widest terms and the bottom right one is the only candidate.

You just need two pairs of columns in the `alignedat` and you can use the `\multispan` trick for the centering:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,parskip=half-,numbers=noenddot,BCOR=8mm,headheight=29pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%MATHEMATIK
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:1}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
c_{0}&=P(Q(0))&&=a_{0}\\
c_{1}&=P'(Q(0))Q'(0)&&=a_{1}b_{1}\\
c_{2}&=\frac{P''(Q(0))Q'(0)^{2}+P'(Q(0))Q''(0)}{2}&&=a_{2}b_{1}^{2}+a_{1}b_{2}\\
c_{3}&\multispan{1}${}=\hfill\cdots\hfill$&&=a_{3}b_{1}^{3}+2a_{2}b_{1}b_{2}+a_{1}b_{3}\\
c_{4}&\multispan{1}${}=\hfill\cdots\hfill$&&=
  \!\begin{aligned}[t]
  &b_{1}^{2}(a_{4}b_{1}^{2}+3a_{3}b_{2})\\
  &\qquad+a_{2}(b_{2}^{2}+2b_{1}b_{3})+a_{1}b_{4}
  \end{aligned}
\\[-1ex]
\multispan{4}\hfill\vdots\hfill
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's how I would typeset the display.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,parskip=half-,numbers=noenddot,BCOR=8mm,headheight=29pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%MATHEMATIK
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:1}
\begin{aligned}
c_{0}&=P(Q(0))\\
     &=a_{0}\\[1ex]
c_{1}&=P'(Q(0))Q'(0)\\
     &=a_{1}b_{1}\\[1ex]
c_{2}&=\frac{P''(Q(0))Q'(0)^{2}+P'(Q(0))Q''(0)}{2}\\
     &=a_{2}b_{1}^{2}+a_{1}b_{2}\\[1ex]
c_{3}&=\cdots\\
     &=a_{3}b_{1}^{3}+2a_{2}b_{1}b_{2}+a_{1}b_{3}\\
c_{4}&=\cdots\\
     &=b_{1}^{2}(a_{4}b_{1}^{2}+3a_{3}b_{2})+a_{2}(b_{2}^{2}+2b_{1}b_{3})+a_{1}b_{4}
\\[-1ex]
&\vdotswithin{=}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why both `amsmath` and `mathtools`?  (naughty!)

Comment: @barbarabeeton It was in the OP's code; actually I prefer to load both.

Answer (score 0):

Since this seems like a singular case and not something that needs a general use-case solution, I think discrete use of `\hspace{}` is a reasonable approach, tuned to the particular needs.

I fixed the width problem by using a stack to break up the last equation over two lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,parskip=half-,numbers=noenddot,BCOR=8mm,headheight=29pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%MATHEMATIK
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:1}
\renewcommand\stackalignment{r}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
&c_{0}&&=P(Q(0))&&=a_{0}\\
&c_{1}&&=P^{\prime}(Q(0))Q^{\prime}(0)&&=a_{1}b_{1}\\
&c_{2}&&=\frac{P^{\prime\prime}(Q(0))Q^{\prime}(0)^{2}+P^{\prime}(Q(0))Q^{\prime\prime}(0)}{2}&&=a_{2}b_{1}^{2}+a_{1}b_{2}\\
&c_{3}&&={}\hspace{77pt}\hdots&&=a_{3}b_{1}^{3}+2a_{2}b_{1}b_{2}+a_{1}b_{3}\\
&c_{4}&&={}\hspace{77pt}\hdots&&=b_{1}^{2}(a_{4}b_{1}^{2}+3a_{3}b_{2})+a_{2}(b_{2}^{2}+\stackunder[5pt]{2b_{1}b_{3}}{+a_{1}b_{4}})\\[-1ex]
& &&\rlap{\hspace{186pt}\vdots}&&
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\centering x\\to test for centering
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\makebox` to create boxes of the correct width:

[image]

The reason the equation number is below is that your equiation is too wide to fit the equation number (as shown by the use of the `showframe` pacakge).

You can apply `\mathrlap` to a portion of the last line:

```
&c_{4}&&=\hcenteredDots&&=b_{1}^{2}(a_{4}b_{1}^{2}+3a_{3}b_{2})+a_{2}(b_{2}^{2}+2b_{1}b_{3})+\mathrlap{a_{1}b_{4}}\\
```

and then the equaiton number won't be underneath:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,parskip=half-,numbers=noenddot,BCOR=8mm,headheight=29pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

%MATHEMATIK
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsmath}% <-- included in mathtools
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand*{\Widest}{\frac{P^{\prime\prime}(Q(0))Q^{\prime}(0)^{2}+P^{\prime}(Q(0))Q^{\prime\prime}(0)}{2}}%
\newcommand*{\hcenteredDots}{\makebox[\widthof{$\displaystyle\Widest$}][c]{$\dotsb$}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eqn:1}
\begin{alignedat}{3}
&c_{0}&&=P(Q(0))&&=a_{0}\\
&c_{1}&&=P^{\prime}(Q(0))Q^{\prime}(0)&&=a_{1}b_{1}\\
&c_{2}&&=\Widest&&=a_{2}b_{1}^{2}+a_{1}b_{2}\\
&c_{3}&&=\hcenteredDots&&=a_{3}b_{1}^{3}+2a_{2}b_{1}b_{2}+a_{1}b_{3}\\
&c_{4}&&=\hcenteredDots&&=b_{1}^{2}(a_{4}b_{1}^{2}+3a_{3}b_{2})+a_{2}(b_{2}^{2}+2b_{1}b_{3})+a_{1}b_{4}\\%[-1ex]
& && &&\makebox[\widthof{=}][r]{\vdots}
\end{alignedat}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```